# Laravel 5 - restricting a record from eloquent all() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an AccountType model which is related to the user table.

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User','account_type_id');
    }
```

We have built the website based on the *AccountType* with data like (Normal User, Editor, Admin) and now we want to add a new type as SuperAdmin which is for the site admin. But we don't want that account type to be displayed where the AccountType::all() code is called and also in the users search result. We have used the all() function in most of the places. So we don't want to change it everywhere. Is there any way to override the default function only for this AccountType model?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you want SuperAdmin account type not to be returned when you call AccountType::all()? Anything else?

Comment: Yes, as the AccountType::all is used in lots of controllers , I want to check if I can restrict the new account type from listing when the all() function is called by overriding the function and checking the id of the new type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, (not the easiest) is to create a global scope.
Like the SoftDelete trait which removes all deleted entities from your queries.

You add a global scope to AccountType to permenently remove SuperAdmin from all of your queries.

Ex: AccountType::all() will return ['Normal User', 'Editor']

And

AccountType::withSuperAdmin()->all() will return the previous array plus the SuperAmin type.

See : http://softonsofa.com/laravel-5-eloquent-global-scope-how-to/

You don't have to use the Sofa Package to make this works.

Open the SoftDelete trait and try to understand why this does.

Answer (score 2):

Add this method to AccountType model. This method will override Model::all() -- default method.

```
public static function all($columns = array('*'))
    {
        $columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();

        $instance = new static;

        return $instance->newQuery()->where('account_type', '!=', 'SuperAdmin')->get($columns);
    }
```

Comment: Original all() method allows calling it with a multiple arguments, each being a name of the column to be fetched. You're missing that part which might break the application if it's calling all() like that. See the original implementation.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo No you are still able to pass the array of columns to this method --- like AccountType::all(['id','account_type']);The only difference is that this method would not return the records where account_type is equal to SuperAdmin

Comment: I meant the other way of calling it: AccountType::all('id', 'account_type') - see missing array notation - which works perfectly with original implementation

Comment: Every time you overwrite a parent function make sure it stays compatible with original one, so that child class can be always used wherever parent class is used - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle. Otherwise you might break existing code relying on original implemenentation

Comment: I have no idea where did you get that the model::all() accepts anything else than array.  This is laravel documentation ---http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all

Comment: From the code latest https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Thank you -- Now, It's up to date.

Comment: You never know what people mean by "Laravel 5" :) Anyway, it is version-proof now

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just put **SuperAdmin** id in your config and overwrite the **all()** method in **AccountType** model:

```
public static function all($columns = ['*'])
{
  $columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();
  return static::where('id', '<>', Config::get('app.super_admin_id')->get($columns);
}
```

If you want to exclude **SuperAdmin** from all SELECT queries that your application does, you could also check Eloquent's **global scopes** - an example is the **SoftDeletes** trait you can read about here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#soft-deleting. It will require much more code and would also work globally so you'd need to update how you fetch account types where you want **SuperAdmin** to be returned.